how can I Increment number inside a excel formula as you copy down the column?
I Currently have the formula below, and I want only the highlighted number to increment as I am copying the formula down the column. show can I make it possible?

I've tried A1 which column has a list of numbers starting from 1 - 5. which works but I want to get rid of that list I have on column A.
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF('Prod Seq Report'!$C$3:$C$379=Schedule!$D$4,'Prod Seq Report'!$B$3:$B$379,""),A1),"")


Use ROWS() function : =IFERROR(SMALL(IF('Prod Seq Report'!$C$3:$C$379=Schedule!$D$4,'Prod Seq Report'!$B$3:$B$379,""),ROWS(A$1:A1)),"")

You would use the =row() formula which outputs the row number of the cell value it is in, or the row of the cell value you put in the (). This means you may have to offset the value to what you want. For example, if your formula goes in row 3, but the first instance needs to be 1, you'd write it as =row()-2 in row 3 so it gives 1.
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF('Prod Seq Report'!$C$3:$C$379=Schedule!$D$4,'Prod Seq Report'!$B$3:$B$379,""),   ROW())   ,"")
Similarly, you can use =rows() which counts how many rows are input into the (). So you you put =rows(c5) this would yield 1 as it is only 1 row high. However, =rows(C5:C10) would yield 6 since it's 6 cells high. You could use this by locking the first row of the array, as Mayukh Bhattacharya mentioned.
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF('Prod Seq Report'!$C$3:$C$379=Schedule!$D$4,'Prod Seq Report'!$B$3:$B$379,""),   ROWS($C$3:C3))   ,"")
This assumes it starts on row 3, so you may have to re-reference the cells that work for your problem, just lock the first cell.
If you need to choose, choose the second formula. The first one is more prone to errors if the table is moved and the static -2 value needs to be maintained.

Make it ROWS() so that if any of the rows gets deleted then the given formula will return #REF! error while ROWS() won't

@MayukhBhattacharya, edited the question to write the formula that way as well. I prefer your method as well, more dynamic.

Mark S. Sir I have learnt this trick from @ScottCraner Sir.

Smart person. Scott, Bigben, & You are some of the best on here. Way to lead by example!
